# How to erase a Hard Disk Drive

Tags: c, linux, erase, hard-drive

This is an odd question, but here it goes. I would like to write a program to flash my external hard drive with 1s and then 0s to clean it completely so I can sell it. Now, why do I want to write my own software instead of just using DBAN?

1. From what I understand, DBAN deletes all hard drives it detects. I only want to clean my external.
2. DBAN flashes seven times. I feel this is a little excessive for my purposes, since my external contains no illegal material nor credit card information.
3. To be honest, I actually am kind of curious as to how firmware works.

Google didn't turn up too much (stupid Adobe Flash). I would prefer doing this in C/C++, but other languages work to, including assembly.

Comment: Just erase everything on the drive, then write a program in whatever language to fill the drive with files of random data.  Yes, a few bits might sneak through here and there, but not enough to be a real concern.

Comment: Use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`.  No need to write a program.

Comment: (And I don't think the term is "flash" -- maybe "scrub".)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Why?  What's the point?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Do you have a source to back that up?  Under what circumstances can one recover a hard drive after `dd if=/dev/zero` where one cannot also do so with `dd if=/dev/[u]random`?

Comment: @JanDvorak: In that case, you should be sure and place a copy of James Joyce's *Ulysses* next to your computer before you begin.  My claim that it helps is unsourced but it doesn't hurt either.  It makes you feel safer (Joyce gives that "warm and safe" feeling).

Comment: lol, I recall that [The Great Zero Challenge](http://hostjury.com/blog/view/195/the-great-zero-challenge-remains-unaccepted) was established to settle this once and for all.  Unfortunately, it likely didn't publicize well enough in order to draw a conclusion.

Comment: @BrianCain Great link. Deleting my former comments.

Comment: IMO it's a little inconclusive.  But I still think it's likely that you might effectively reduce the potential pool of attackers to only nation states.

Comment: This isn't an actual answerable question. "I wanna write a program that...because I don't want to use what's already out there.". Seriously?

Comment: @KenWhite The question looks valid to me. You don't have to justify your reasons when asking questions here. If people want to learn how to write a program that erases a disk, I don't see a reason to not accept their question.

Comment: Related Super User post:  http://superuser.com/q/19326/169038

Comment: This demonstrates a very poor approach to problem solving on several levels. First, take the effort to find out what DBAN's capabilities actually are. And note that it is open source.

Comment: vote up for `stupid adobe flash`.   LOL

Comment: @NikosC: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) says "specific, concise questions", and that some effort to solve the problem yourself should be shown. It's also frequently said here that this is not a tutorial site, or a substitute for a personal research assistant. "I wanna write..." is not sufficient effort, IMO, and it is definitely not a *specific, concise* question.

Comment: Disk wiping operates at a higher level than the firmware level. If you want to learn how firmware works, I suggest you get an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) and learn to program it. Keep working at that, and you will eventually figure out how things like hard disk drive and motherboard firmware work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, doing it in C is rather easy. First, you open the appropriate device file in write mode:

```
int fd = open("/dev/sdc", O_WRONLY);
```

and you simply `write()` 512 byte chunks to it until you can write no more. Newer disks use 4096 byte sectors instead, but the OS usually treats them as if they have 512 byte sectors, so 512 is the safest value. Here's a C program that does exactly this:

(Note: Be *very* careful to choose the correct /dev device file, or else you're going to wipe out the wrong disk!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/sdd", O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening device file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Write 0's all over the disk, in chunks of 512 bytes.
    char* zeros = calloc(1, 512);
    ssize_t written, total = 0;
    do {
        total += written = write(fd, zeros, 512);
        printf("\rBytes written: %ld", total);
    } while (written == 512);
    printf("\nDone!\n");

    close(fd);
    free(zeros);
    return 0;
}
```

You might get a speed-up if you remove the `printf()`, though it's kind of cool to see the progress as it happens. You should probably also do additional error checking at the end (if `written` is -1, an error occurred, and you should check `errno`.)

Note that due to caching, the program might appear to hang at the end for a little while after it prints "Done". It's not really hanging, it's only that the caching of the write operations is blocking it until they're all finished.

Answer (score 2):

> From what I understand, DBAN deletes all hard drives it detects. I only want to clean my external.

[It doesn't](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/screenshots/84360).

> DBAN flashes seven times. I feel this is a little excessive for my purposes, since my external contains no illegal material nor credit card information.

But when you wake up in the morning, it's done, right?  Also, it's [apparently configurable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/screenshots/84362).

> To be honest, I actually am kind of curious as to how firmware works.

IMO, this isn't the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

As a note. Your question seems to be about erasing data, aka shredding etc.

Flashing a HDD would be to update the internal software. As in: an [HDD has its own firmware](http://www.databe.com/articles/article6.html). Under Linux you can do i.e.:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

You will then get information such as:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST31000524AS                            
    Serial Number:      XXXXXXX
    Firmware Revision:  JC4B    
    Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
```

...

Tho this  is the other way around, you can look at / search forensics. I.e. [FAU](http://www.gmgsystemsinc.com/fau/), [Open Source Digital Forensics](http://www2.opensourceforensics.org/tools) etc. to get more information.

[A bit more on wiping](https://www.anti-forensics.com/disk-wiping-one-pass-is-enough/).

Comment: You're very much on the right track.  `hdparm` can also be used to invoke the firmware-level [secure-erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) feature present on all modern ATA drives.